# Python -> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when using pyModbusTCP to read_holding_registers() AFTER read_coils()

Tags: python-3.x, exception, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

For clarity I am using Python3.10.9 with pyModbusTCP 0.2.0 to communicate with a PLC. I have several grouping of coils which I read using the `read_coils()` method from the package, and I use the `read_holding_register()` to read individual holding registers.

I have strange problem where if I first read the holding registers, and afterwards I read the coils I have no issues. If I try to read the coils first, and afterwards try to read the holding registers I get the error from the title`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

I don't know the exact model of the PLC but I am assuming it's an issue with my Python, below is a basic idea of how I am reading things:

```
    def readManyCoils(self):
        coilData = self.ModbusClient_call.read_coils(self.modbus_address, self.modbus_address_read_count)
        return coilData
```

```
    try:
        # Read coils 0-34 => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 16, 32, 33, 34
        all_modbus_coils1 = read_from_modbus.ReadFromModbusAddress(gvl.production_coil1,
                                                                   gvl.global_plc1, 34)

        coils1_list = all_modbus_coils1.readManyCoils()

        print(f'\ncoils1_list => {coils1_list}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error => {e}')
```

I have several sets of the above where I read groupings of coils, and below is how I read registers

```
    def readSingleRegister(self):
        holdingRegisterData = self.ModbusClient_call.read_holding_registers(self.modbus_address)
        return holdingRegisterData[0]
```

```
def read_modbus_timer():

    read__timer = read_from_modbus.ReadFromModbusAddress(gvl.production_register_timer, gvl.global_plc1)

    timer = read_erector_timer.readSingleRegister()


    return timer
```

```
    try:
        # Read holding register 100
        register1 = read_modbus_timer()
        print(f'register1 => {register1}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error => {e}')
```

So one more time my particular issue is that when I read the holding registers AFTER I read the coils I get the exception, even if I let the program sleep for 10s. If I read the registers BEFORE I read the coils there are no issues at all. Does anyone know WHY this is happening? THANKS!

Comment: Its difficult to see how the code fragments you supplied fit together; can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (if the issue is what you think then you should be able to replicate this in a small, self contained, example). `read_coils` returns `None` if an error occurs; this explains the error the cause of the problem (setting `debug=True` when creating `ModbusClient` might provide info on that)

Comment: @Brits For your curiosity, even if an address is not mapped read_coils was returning false for that value. This was an issue that had to be resolved on the other device end, mapping all the unused in between coils. I do not know why it worked, but no issues after that. C'est la vie